# Integrating a java applet in a page

Tags: java, jsp, applet

I am trying to integrate a processing applet in a jsp, with the following code added in the jsp:

```
<!--<applet code="Test1.class" archive="C:\Users\user\Desktop\MyApplet.jar" width="600" height="600">
</applet> --!>
```

I am using a tomcat server. The jar contains the Test1.class file. But whenever I run this page, I am getting an error in the webpage. On clicking for details, the message shown is

```
IllegalArgumentException: name![enter image description here][1]
```

Comment: The code shown is commented out.  It would have utterly no effect.  Prepare a short HTML (**not** JSP) that has only the applet element, try it, then edit the question with the entire (short) HTML if it fails.

Comment: I intentionally commented it out while putting it on the forum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Minimalist example:

```
<applet 
  code="Test1" 
  codebase="."
  archive="MyApplet.jar" 
  width=400
  height=400>
</applet>
```

- `code` - The fully qualified class name  (e.g. `javax.swing.JApplet`)
- `codebase` - A `.` indicates 'the current directory' - where the HTML is loaded from.  Although the current directory is the default, I like to make it explicit.
- `archive` - Relative path(s) from codebase to archive(s).  For simplicity, the archive is assumed to be the same place as the HTML.
- `width`/`height` - Must be specified.

Comment: OK. Got it. I wasn't using the fully qualified class name. Should be like, packagename.Test1. But now I am getting a NoClassDefFound Error for processing/core/PApplet. My class Test1 extends PApplet class. It's from core jar for Processing plugin. Also, I am using a html file now.   <html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<applet code="package1.Test1" name="myApplet" archive="MyApplet.jar" codebase="." width="600" height="600">
</applet>
</body>
</html>

Comment: I have imported the processing jar also.

Comment: Thanks guys got it. I had to add core.jar with a comma separator with the MyApplet.jar in the archive attribute. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the "codebase" attribute to set the path. Consider to put it in the same folder (or in a child folder of the current one) *instead of an absolute path*.

```
<applet code="Test1" name="yourName" archive="MyApplet.jar" codebase="C:\Users\user\Desktop">
</applet>
```

Comment: What's the name attribute here for? Doesn't the value has any significance here?

Comment: No, "name" is not a required attribute and the value I have set is just for example purpose.

Comment: OK got it. My first predicament is still not solved. I have put the jar file in a folder and put the absolute path in the codebase tag (for the folder) but it still doesn't work. This time there is no error on the page though. Just the page is empty. Sorry if I come across as lame but I am new at this. Here is the code:     
<applet code="Test1" name="myApplet" archive="MyApplet.jar" codebase="C:\Users\user\Desktop\New folder" width="600" height="600">
</applet>

Comment: I advised you not to use absolute path. If your folder is named "jarfolder" set codebase with value "jarfolder" only :
<applet code="Test1" archive="MyApplet.jar" codebase="jarfolder">
</applet>

Comment: This gives me a classnotfound exception. If one doesn't use the absolute path, how does the page refers to the correct folder?

Comment: The JAR will be found relative to the current page.
If the JSP is in `src/main/webapp` in your development env, your the applet JAR should, in my previous example, be placed in `src/main/webapp/jarfolder`.

Answer (score 0):

In the case you use Tomcat you can deploy the applet as...

- A) put your jar + its html launch page to the same folder (still I
  recommend a war file and its **WEB-INF** folder)
- B) and configure applet tag as

> ```
>  <applet code="Test1" archive="MyApplet.jar" codebase="."  width="600" height="600">
>     </applet>
> ```

To be more... clear the files structure should look like the following tree...

|webapps

||aWarFile.war

|||WEB-INF

|||MyApplet.jar

|||MyAppletLauncher.html (or *.jsp)

---

Report that helps

Good luck

Comment: Thanks guys got it. I had to add core.jar with a comma separator with the MyApplet.jar in the archive attribute. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
<applet code="package1.Test1" name="myApplet" archive="MyApplet.jar,core.jar" codebase="." width="600" height="600">
```

The above code got me the result.